# Add a new column dynamically in resultset

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query as below;

Existing Query - select A,B,C from table1.

Table2 has columns X,Y

The new query should have a new column(D) in the result-set. the value of D will be calculated based on column X.

D's calculation should be D = (C * X), Here to decide the row of column X from table2 -Y can be used in where condition. Y & A are not same but similar

Comment: [SQL Inner Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what did you mean by "Y & A are not same but similar". I assume Y and A can be used as joining keys. If so, the anwer would be:

```
SELECT T1.A,T1.B,T1.C,T1.C*T2.X AS D
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.A=T2.Y
```

I hope this helps!